# How to Include and Exclude Some of Files From Different Artifacts Using Maven Shaded Plugin

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to create a uber jar using Maven Shaded plugin to do that i have created a Maven profile.I have two dependency projects related to current project.

Project-A **Depends on** Project-B and Project-C. All of them share same **group id**. we are using monolith repo structure.Below are projects .pom details

**Project-A.pom**

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sample.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sample.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>Project-C</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

   <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shade</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifactSet>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
                                            <exclude>LICENSE</exclude>
                                            <exclude>*:*</exclude> // exclude all artifacts
                                             <exclude>com.sample.manual:*</exclude> // exclude specific artifact

                                        </excludes>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>com.sample.project:*</include> //include only com.sample.project related artifacts
                                        </includes>
                                    </artifactSet>
                                    <transformers>
                                        <transformer
                                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                                        <transformer
                                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                        </transformer>
                                    </transformers>

                                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                                    <shadedClassifierName>jar-with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName>
                                    <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

My requirement is that i want to exclude all **.xml** files from dependent projects and only include Xml files from current project.To do that i have used following filters but i can not achieve it.

```
<exclude>com.sample.project:*.xml</exclude>
<include>com.sample.project:{project.artifactId}:*.xml</include>
```

Please let me know how to do it.